# Updating matched version using regex with Powershell

Tags: powershell

Everything works fine when the character before the first dot is 1, but I am struggling to find a solution when the symbols are more than 1. Any hint/help is appreciated :)

```
$patternRegx = '^(\d+\.){3}(\d+)$'
$pathToVersion = "D:\version.txt" ---> #contains string "1.2.3.4"
$appVersion = Get-Content $pathToVersion

if ($appVersion -match $patternRegx) {
    Write-Host "Version $appVersion is valid" -BackgroundColor Blue

    Write-Host "Updating the version.." -BackgroundColor Blue
    $updateMajor = [int]::Parse($appVersion[0]) + 1
    $appVersion = $appVersion -replace '^\d+\.',"$updateMajor." | Set-Content -Path $pathToVersion
    $appVersion = Get-Content $pathToVersion
    Write-Host "$appVersion" -BackgroundColor Blue

}
else {
    Write-Host "Invalid version!"
}
```

Comment: Can you provide an example list of string patterns supposed to succeed and one to those supposed to fail ?

Comment: So the pattern must be x.x.x.x with only numeric values. The succeed and fail statements are working fine, only the updating logic doesn't work.

Comment: just FYI, there is a slightly more direct method to test for "is this a valid version number?". this >>> `if ('1.2.3.4' -as [version]) {'Good!'} else {'__BAD__'}` <<< will show `Good!`. however, if you change the string to something like `a.2.3.4`, you will get `__BAD__`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here two ways of doing what you want:

The first method uses the System.Version object to increment the Major element:

```
$patternRegx   = '^(\d+\.){3}(\d+)$'
$pathToVersion = "D:\version.txt" #contains string "1.2.3.4"
$appVersion    = Get-Content $pathToVersion

if ($appVersion -match $patternRegx) {
    Write-Host "Version $appVersion is valid" -BackgroundColor Blue
    # convert into a System.Version object
    $current = [version]$appVersion

    # create new version by incrementing the $current.Major element
    $newVersion = [version]::new($current.Major + 1, $current.Minor, $current.Build, $current.Revision)

    Write-Host "Updating the version.." -BackgroundColor Blue
    $newVersion.ToString() | Set-Content -Path $pathToVersion

    # prove the new version is stored correctly
    $appVersion = Get-Content $pathToVersion
    Write-Host "$appVersion" -BackgroundColor Blue
}
else {
    Write-Host "Invalid version!"
}
```

As alternative you can use `-split` and `-join` like this:

```
if ($appVersion -match $patternRegx) {
    Write-Host "Version $appVersion is valid" -BackgroundColor Blue
    # split into integers
    $version = [int[]]($appVersion -split '\.')
    # incrementing the first element
    $version[0]++

    Write-Host "Updating the version.." -BackgroundColor Blue
    # join the array with dots
    $version -join '.' | Set-Content -Path $pathToVersion

    # prove the new version is stored correctly
    $appVersion = Get-Content $pathToVersion
    Write-Host "$appVersion" -BackgroundColor Blue
}
else {
    Write-Host "Invalid version!"
}
```

Hope that helps

Comment: i keep hunting for a way to add & subtract version numbers. all i ever find it what you used ... and it really seems that there otta be a more direct way. [*sigh ...*]

Comment: @Lee_Dailey It was a pain for a newbie like me.. Keep hunting !

Comment: @Lee_Dailey I totally agree! The properties Major, Minor etc. are all Read-Only. I have never understood why..

Answer (score 0):

[@Theo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9898643/theo) Thank you for the help.

I have manage to solve it yesterday, but I will try your way too necessarily :) The full code is:

```
$patternRegx = '^(\d+\.){3}(\d+)$'
$pathToVersion = "D:\version.txt"
$appVersion = Get-Content $pathToVersion


if ($appVersion -match $patternRegx) {
    Write-Host "Version $appVersion is valid." -BackgroundColor DarkGreen
    Write-Host "Updating the version.." -BackgroundColor Blue
    $majorVersion = $appVersion.Split(".")
    $updateMajor = [int]::Parse($majorVersion[0]) + 1
    $majorVersion = $majorVersion -join "." -replace '^\d+\.',"$updateMajor." | Set-Content -Path $pathToVersion
    $newVersion = Get-Content $pathToVersion
    Write-Host "$newVersion" -BackgroundColor Blue

}
else {
    Write-Host "Invalid version!" -BackgroundColor Red
}
```